# Sending form reminders from my business email instead of Cognito forms email

Tags: cognito-forms

Can I have the form reminders come from info@mybusines.com instead of the info@cognitoforms address header? I don't want to confuse customers or have to create rules for spam with each customer. I can't seem to find a way to use the form reminders in which the content is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely! When sending confirmation emails in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), you can specify a from name and email address to be anything you want.  You can also include entry details and even include a PDF copy of the form submission:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am getting all the correct output (Title company name and reply to address) except the 'from' email shows as noreply@cognitoforms.com instead of my input email. The reply to address is correct (for example when you hit 'reply to' it routes to my business address).

Comment: Gotcha.  Due to email rules, it is not possible for us to send email directly from your email account without permission from your email provider and your account credentials.  Instead we follow industry best practices and set the Reply To and Display Name to reflect your organization while having the From address match our domain.  In most email clients, the Reply To and Display Name are correctly featured as the From address.

Comment: Jamie, thanks for the thoughts. That makes sense. I can provide my business email provider information Microsoft 365 account (which I am the owner) and account credentials. I would like to send directly from info@hbcprogress.com if possible. Let me know who I may contact for this transition. Thanks.

Comment: [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) does not currently support SMTP relay.  We may add this in the future, but is not something we can configure right now for your account.